# Accelerator resource table giving errors

Tags: c++, winapi

What's wrong with the following resource definition ?

```
ACCELERATOR_RESOURCE_ID ACCELERATORS
LANGUAGE LANG_ENGLISH, SUBLANG_ENGLISH_US
{
    VK_C, IDA_COPY, NOINVERT, CONTROL, VIRTKEY
    VK_V, IDA_PASTE, NOINVERT, CONTROL, VIRTKEY
    VK_A, IDA_SELECTALL, NOINVERT, CONTROL, VIRTKEY 
}
```

It gives me syntax error at the line **VK_C, IDA_COPY, NOINVERT, CONTROL, VIRTKEY** everytime I compile. And I can't pinpoint the problem.

Comment: This is not valide C/c++ code.

Comment: Do you have IDA_COPY defined somewhere (resource.h or similar?) and/or that file then #included into this .rc file?

Comment: @Yirkha Yes, I have, other resources are working perfectly.

Comment: @MichaelWalz Can you please expand on it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Virtual key identifiers for plain letters or numbers are not defined in Windows headers -- from WinUser.h:

```
/*
 * VK_0 - VK_9 are the same as ASCII '0' - '9' (0x30 - 0x39)
 * 0x40 : unassigned
 * VK_A - VK_Z are the same as ASCII 'A' - 'Z' (0x41 - 0x5A)
 */
```

Therefore the values `VK_C`, `VK_V` etc. are the problem.

Character constants like `'C'` or `'V'` are apparently not supported by the Resource Compiler and the practice seems to use (hex) numeric ASCII values instead:

```
0x43, IDA_COPY, NOINVERT, CONTROL, VIRTKEY
0x56, IDA_PASTE, NOINVERT, CONTROL, VIRTKEY
0x41, IDA_SELECTALL, NOINVERT, CONTROL, VIRTKEY
```

Comment: That did the trick, thanks a lot. I didn't know that those were not defined in the header :o